# Konva.js Cache Scale

Tags: konvajs

Problem is when using node.cache() the node is first cached then scaled. How to achive first scaling then caching ? Thx in advance.

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: document.getElementById('stage'),
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
var group1 = new Konva.Group();
var group2 = new Konva.Group();

var text1 = new Konva.Text({
  text:'Test',
  scale: {x:10,y:10},
  x:10,
  y:10
});

var text2 = new Konva.Text({
  text:'Test',
  scale: {x:10,y:10},
  x:50,
  y:50
});

text1.cache();

layer.add(text1);
layer.add(text2)
stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to work with transformations if node will be transformed before cache. As workaround you can add transformed node to a group, then cache the group.

```
var text1 = new Konva.Text({
  text:'Test',
  scale: {x:10,y:10},
  x:10,
  y:10
});
group1.add(text1);
group1.cache();
```

http://jsbin.com/fotano/edit?html,js,output